# Program crashes only when traced

Tags: c, gdb, stack

Sometimes, when I have a C function with a lot of stack variables (say struct mystruct m[1000]), the program crashes on entry into this function *only when debugging with gdb*.

Could you explain a little bit what happens there? Sorry if this is not a "real" question, but I think I could learn from answers.

Comment: You are probably very close to the maximum stack size and GDB is inserting infor into the stack to aid debugging ... that would be my guess anyway ...

Comment: a Heisenbug can also result from an uninitialised variable in line 42.

Comment: are you sure it crashes *on entry*? what happens if the 1000 is changed to something lower?

Comment: What is `sizeof(struct mystruct)`?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check ulimit -s.
Can you post your program here so that we could see what are you trying to do in the function.